# How to enable absolute imports in Create React App v4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I've recently updated CRA to v4 and now webpack doesn't recognize absolute imports. This error appears:

`TypeError: store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.model is not a function`

import looks like this:

```
import store from 'store';
```

and it imports store from src folder

My jsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

With CRA v3 it works perfectly fine.
How can I make this work without ejecting?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is done already which is having to create a JavaScript configuration file named `jsconfig.json` or TypeScript Configuration file named `tsconfig.json` in the `root` directory of your project, in the use-case of TypeScript it is automatically created from the start.

In your `jsconfig.json` replace what you have with this to include `src`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: Can you update your question with the import statements you have? And if a CodeSandbox demo is available, that would help also.